# Centos 5.4 (x86_64) DNS resolution woes

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, bind, centos5, opendns

I've setup a Centos 5.4 (x86_64) box in a VM recently; the trouble is I just can't get internet to work on it.

Pinging the resolved google.com ips, nameserver ips works fine but DNS lookup queries don't.

Here's some of the digging around that I did:

```
dig google.com
; <<>> DiG 9.3.6-P1-RedHat-9.3.6-4.P1.el5 <<>> google.com
;; global options:  printcmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

nslookup google.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I didn't observe any UDP/TCP packets during dig and nslookup either

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

Also my /etc/nsswitch.conf is in order and contains the "hosts: files dns"

What could be wrong?

Comment: I'll definitely update you you guys on this as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: I had openSUSE 11.1 installed in a VM as well, DNS worked fine in it.

Comment: UPDATE:

I tried with FreeBSD8 as well and DNS query didn't work. This is beginning to look more and more like an issue with my UTStarcom WA3002G4 ADSL2+ Router and its NAT or the lack of it.

My setup and the ip addresses:
Router         192.168.1.1
Windows      192.168.1.2
Centos 5.4   192.168.1.3
FreeBSD8    192.168.1.4

The windows host works fine with no issues with DNS queries.

Comment: Would be glad to email you the packet dump file, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

1. Rule out **iptables**:

   service iptables stop

Do the nslookup. If it works then inspect your ruleset and retry. Don't forget to restart iptables.

2. Try telnetting to port 53 of those ip addresses:

   telnet 208.67.220.220 53

You should see:

```
$   telnet 208.67.220.220 53
Trying 208.67.220.220...
Connected to 208.67.220.220.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: nslookup didn't work, but telnet did.

Answer (score 1):

Can you ping the DNS servers that were specified in resolv.conf?

Comment: yes I can ping them

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and this question pointed me to the spot to fix it.

After banging my head against a wall for three days it turned out that my modem was the issue. DHCP was set locally which was causing havoc for my firewall.

After turning off DHCP on the modem and restarting it my name server was working perfectly.